# Docusign - User management REST API for Incremental Search - List all Users?

Tags: docusignapi

For Docusign User Management REST API, I like to filtered the users with parameters createdDateTime, LastLogin , userProfileLastModifiedDate same as email_substring and email. Is there any optional query parameters available for Incremental search?

Answer (score 0):

Per [DS Docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Users/Users/list/), currently createdDateTime, LastLogin, userProfileLastModifiedDate are not supported. You need to search on available query parameters, then you need to filter out in your system with the extra filter criteria.

Comment: In List All Users API , Can we pass the value of createdDateTime, LastLogin, userProfileLastModifiedDate in filter option? @Amit K Bist

Comment: No, currently this API does not support these values